# Unable to insert data into sqlite3 database using PHP

Tags: php, sqlite

I've been trying to get my PHP code to insert data into my sqlite3 database. I have read the documentation for using sqlite3 with PHP, and have tried to follow it carefully. Here is the specific syntax on how to do insertion queries in PHP for sqlite3: https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.exec.php

Here is some insertion code I am trying to execute. Each variable value in the query is gathered from an html form.

```php
$db->exec("
   INSERT INTO BOOK(Title,Author,Genre,ISBN_number,Age_rating,Language,Book_review,Price)
   VALUES (
'$Btitle', '$BAuthor', '$BGenre', '$BISBN', '$age', '$lan', '$bookRev', '$pr')
");
```

This code does not throw any errors. However, when I do a selection query through PHP to display the books, the entry from this line of code is not in the table.

Comment: It's good to use parameterized statement to prevent SQL injection issues.

Comment: @Zhorov Good catch. However, even when I save the insertion query to a variable, and then do a prepare and execution statement while binding the parameters (which are also available options when using sqlite3 with php), it still doesn't appear on the table.

Comment: Then, probably a write permissions (_SQLite3 may need to create temporary files during the execution of queries, so the respective directories may have to be writable._) issue? What does `echo $db->lastErrorMsg();` return after `SQLite3::prepare`, `SQLite3Stmt::execute` calls?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the problem. The form's submit tag in the html had the value "Submit" instead of "Submit Action".